# Implementing hyper::Service on a reference to a struct

Tags: rust, hyper

I'm trying to make a question and answer server for a huge data structure. The user would send JSON questions to the server and the server would use the huge data structure to answer.

I'm trying to do this by implementing the `hyper::server::Service` trait for my `Oracle` struct.

I've got something like this:

```
use self::hyper::server::{Http, Service, Request, Response};
// ...other imports

struct Oracle { /* Tons of stuff */}

impl<'a> Service for &'a Oracle {
    type Request = Request;
    type Response = Response;
    type Error = hyper::Error;
    type Future = Box<Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>>;

    fn call(&self, req: Request) -> Self::Future {
         match (req.method(), req.path()) {
            // could be lots of question types
            (&hyper::Method::Post, "/query") => {
                Box::new(req.body().concat2().map(|b| {
                    let query: Query = deserialize_req(&b.as_ref());
                    let ans = get_answer(&self, &query);
                    Response::new()
                        .with_header(ContentLength(ans.len() as u64))
                        .with_body(ans)
                }))
            },
            _ => {
                let response = Response::new()
                    .with_status(hyper::StatusCode::NotFound);
                Box::new(futures::future::ok(response))
            },
        }
    }
}
```

This causes lifetime problems (`cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements`) when I try to put `&self` in a future.

My inclination is that this is totally the wrong way to approach this problem, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to do this.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE]. Your question has numerous undefined types, types which are probably not even relevant to the question. Prune down your code to the bare minimum. In addition, **always** include the *entire* error message, not just the one line summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that these futures are going to be compute-intensive, it would make sense to run them on a [CPU pool](https://crates.io/crates/futures-cpupool) and avoid running them on the asynchronous single-threaded Tokio Core stack.

The `&self` in the `call` is a reference to a memory managed by the call site. The call site might free that memory right after the call, or at some other time we don't control, therefore saving the reference in the closure ("closing over the reference") for some later use is wrong.

In order to manage the memory in a way that lends better to sharing you'd often use a reference-counting pointer. The `Oracle` memory will then be owned by the reference-counting pointer rather than the call site, allowing you to freely share the `Oracle` with closures and threads.

If you want to process these futures in parallel, you'd need a thread-safe reference-counting pointer, such as `Arc`.

To use the `Arc`, you could turn the `call` into a free function:

```
fn call(oracle: Arc<Oracle>, req: Request) -> OracleFuture
```

Or use a trait to implement the `call` on the pointer:

```
struct Oracle { /* Tons of stuff */}

type OraclePt = Arc<Oracle>;

trait OracleIf {
  fn call(&self, req: Request) -> Self::Future
}

impl OracleIf for OraclePt {
  fn call(&self, req: Request) -> Self::Future {
    ...
            let oracle: OraclePt = self.clone();
            Box::new(req.body().concat2().map(move |b| {  // Close over `oracle`.
                let query: Query = deserialize_req(&b.as_ref());
                let ans = get_answer(&*oracle, &query);
                Response::new()
                    .with_header(ContentLength(ans.len() as u64))
                    .with_body(ans)
            }))
  }
}
```

We close over the copy of the reference-counting pointer here.

If you don't like the idea of using the reference-counting pointers, then another option is to use a "scoped thread pool", a thread pool that guarantees that the child threads are terminated before the parent thread, making it possible to safely share the `Oracle` reference with the child threads.
It might be easier to do the latter without wrapping the computation in a `Future`.